# tensorflow 2.7 load saved model error with java

Tags: java, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have saved a model in saved model format with tf2.7 and loaded success using:

```
       model = tf.saved_model.load(export_dir=export_dir)
```

when i use saved_model_cli to check this model, it rereturns:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['examples'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: input_example_tensor:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['cf_1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: ParseExample/ParseExampleV2:0
    outputs['cf_2'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: ParseExample/ParseExampleV2:1
    outputs['cf_label'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: ParseExample/ParseExampleV2:2
    outputs['score'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: score:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

but when i try to use java to load this model as follows, it goes wrong:

```
    val bundle = tf.SavedModelBundle.load("/Users/jiyue/git/dl_flow/model_dir_cfck/1646106315","serve")

  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>tensorflow</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

the error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.tensorflow.TensorFlowException: Op type not registered 'ParseExampleV2' in binary running on xxxx. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
```

i need some one help me solve it , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have written a library to import and manage saved models. Have a look if you  want: [JavaTF](https://github.com/preafixed/Java-TF)

If you want you can just follow the instructions I provided on the Readme file, and test the functionality.

You can run Object Detection (inference), and get detections.You can also draw bounding boxes.

Let me know if it helps :)